# Set style on all nodes on top of edges in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-styles, edge

I have some edges with a node 'on top of it' defined as

```
\path (source) edge node {some text} (target);
```

But now it just prints `some text` directly on top of the node, which makes it difficult to read.

What I want is a white background. I know that I can obtain this with

```
\path (source) edge node [fill=white] {some text} (target);
```

but I want this to happen to ALL my nodes, which are on top of an edge.

One way to do it, is to use

```
\tikzset{every node/.style={fill=white}}
```

but then it will happen to all my nodes and not just those node which are on top of edges.

Another way to do it is to set a class manually on all those nodes with

```
\tikzset{white bg/.style={fill=white}}
\path (source) edge node [white bg] {some text} (target);
```

but it would be better if it could be done for all nodes automatically.

Are there any tikz key which does something like

```
\tikzset{every node on edge/.style={fill=white}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an `every edge` style, and you can put an `every node` style definition inside that, so borrowing some code from [gernot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346856/586):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every edge/.append style={every node/.style={fill=blue}}]
\node (source) {S};
\draw (4,0) node (target) {T}; % just to show that this isn't blue either
\path (source) edge node {some text} (target);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a key specific to nodes on paths, since as far as I know,`\node` internally also becomes a `node`. However, you can collect the nodes that you want to affect with `every node` in a scope and define `every node` only for them. The example below shows that after the scope, the `every node` option is no longer effective.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (source) [fill=red] {S};
\node (target) [fill=blue] at (4,0) {T};
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={fill=white}]
  \path (source) edge node {some text} (target);
\end{scope}
\path (0,-1) edge node {some text} (4,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```